# Problem getting rewrite from subdomain to directory to work

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `demo.example.com` to `example.com/my-demo`. This is my rewrite rule, but I'm not getting it to work on my production server:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-demo/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, you are redirecting to the same host. ie. `demo.example.com/file` is redirecting to `demo.example.com/my-demo/file`, not `example.com/my-demo/file`, which is going to result in a redirect loop. You need to specify an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` substitution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =demo.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/my-demo/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

put this in `.htaccess` file in you're demo.example.com directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/demo/$1 [L,R=301]
```

i.e: demo.example.com is in folder root-folder/demo
put that `.htaccess` file on folder **demo**, not on **root-folder**.

hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ServerAlias `demo.example.com` for the VirtualHost that has this `RewriteRule`? If you don't, that is the reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a ServerAlias but a subdomain, remember to put your .htacces file in the subdomain, not in the main domain directory. Also add "RewriteEngine On" in .htaccess if you did not yet.

Comment: It depends on the way one has configured the subdomain. The same effect can be achieved with both a `ServerAlias` and separate VirtualHost for the subdomain.